# Changing bitmap image dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm having issues of having an bitmap image change dynamically between UserControl and Page load.

I'm using a dispatcher timer to keep the image changed. However it does not work. The error stated that my uriSource is null.

I'm using ms visual studio 2012, metro application c#

Code in UserControl xaml:

```
    <Image x:Name="img">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=BitmapImage}" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

Code in UserControl:

```
        public BitmapImage BitmapImage
        { 
            get { return _bitmapImage; }
            set
            {
                if (_bitmapImage == value) return;
                _bitmapImage = value;
                 RaisePropertyChanged("BitmapImage");
            }
         }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Codes in Page load:

```
    int eyesState = 1;

    private void minionAnimation_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
      if (eyesState == -1)
        {

            ghosts[0]._bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/test.png");
        }
        else
        {
            ghosts[0]._bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/test2.png");
        }

        eyesState *= -1;
    }
```

Comment: did you check that it is _not_ ?

Comment: Hi @Tigran ,are you referring to the "PropertyChanged != null" ? I'm sorry, I'm still new at this.

Comment: I mean, the actual value comiler refers is not null

Comment: Hi, @Tigran the error points at the ghosts[0]._bitmapImage.UriSource ... It says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I hope this answers your question..

Comment: Seem ghost[0] is nul. Put a break point on the line and check either ghosts[0] contain value or it is null.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

XAML:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=BitmapImageUri}" />
```

Code:

```
private Uri _bitmapImageUri;
public Uri BitmapImageUri
{
    get { return _bitmapImageUri; }
    set
    {
        if (_bitmapImageUri == value) return;
        _bitmapImageUri= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("BitmapImageUri");
    }
}
```

In timer:

```
ghosts[0].BitmapImageUri = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/test.png");
```